# dialog --menu selected option

Tags: linux, shell, menu, dialog

My script is:

```
dialog --title 'Example' --menu 'Select:' 0 0 0 1 'ABC' 2 'DEF' 3 'GHI'
```

I would like that option 2 was selected by default (over). Its possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
dialog --title 'Example' --default-item '2' --menu 'Select:' 0 0 0 1 'ABC' 2 'DEF' 3 'GHI'
```

Answer (score 0):

dialog --title "Example" --default-item '2' --menu "Select:" 25 25 3   1 "ABC" 2 "DEF" 3 "GHI"

use of  ["] for strings is most recommended
--default-item is common option provided into dialog utilities for menu box or forms.
This will keep selection on '2' option.